# MVVM Light and SL3 Commanding

Tags: mvvm, mvvm-light

I am familar with MVVM. Actually been doing most of my learning in SL4. However, with a recent need, I have to use SL3. I am attempting to use MVVM Light v3 with SL3 and utilize commanding. The problem is that in SL3 there is no Command attribute for buttons. I managed to find an old article (http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2009/09/26/using-relaycommands-in-silverlight-and-wpf.aspx), but I am having trouble figuring out the ButtonBaseExtensions.Command. It appears it is no longer available in GalaSoft.MvvmLight even though the namespace GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command is.

So the question is how can I use MVVM Light v3 with SL3 and leverage commanding? Do I use MVVM Light v2? Can v2 and v3 coexist on the same machine?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [EventToCommand behavior](http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2009/11/05/mvvm-light-toolkit-v3-alpha-2-eventtocommand-behavior.aspx) to still do commanding with buttons in Silverlight 3.

Answer (score 0):

You need these lines of code to make the above XAML work:

```
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WP7"
```